# Go upper folder/directory VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a file/folder explorer using a `ListView`, when clicking a folder, it shows its contents, but I can't make it go back to where I was before opening that folder, or better going on an upper folder. example I'm in `D:\Folder1\Subfolder1\Subfolder` and I want to go to its upper folder, I should be in `D:\Folder1\Subfolder1`, Everytime I click a button.

And i have this code but what it does is it replaces all paths, making it looks like this `D:\Folder1` and I can't go back further. By the way the `Textbox` has a default value/text of `D:\Folder`.

this is my code:

```
Dim lvs As String
Private Sub ListView1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.DoubleClick
    lvs = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text.ToString
    Form2.TextBox1.Text = Form2.TextBox1.Text & "\" & lvs
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim s As String = Form2.TextBox1.Text
    s.Replace("\" & lvs, " ").TrimEnd()
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

Hi, I updated my code, what I did was I'm putting the `ListView` items in an `Array` and I'm deleting the last element(the last folder path) and it works fine. but when I run my code, It only execute once and it cannot be repeated, what could be wrong?

code:

```
Dim lvs As New List(Of String)
Private Sub ListView1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.DoubleClick
    If ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
            lvs.Add(item.Text)
        Next
    End If
        Form2.TextBox1.Text = Form2.TextBox1.Text & "\" & ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text
End Sub

 Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Label5.Text = Label5.Text.Replace("\" & lvs.ElementAt(lvs.Count - 1), "")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone helped me with my updated code that i just have to put this `lvs.RemoveAt(lvs.Count - 1)`, because i was only removing the item in the `Label` but not in the `List(Of String)`(that i thought is an Array, haha).

My `Button` should look like this:

```
Label5.Text = Label5.Text.Replace("\" & lvs(lvs.Count - 1), "")
lvs.RemoveAt(lvs.Count - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to store the full path to the current folder in a string variable. You would then get the path of the parent folder by:

```
Dim parentPath As String = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(currentPath)
```

Once you've done that you then need to make that new path the current path, which is probably what you weren't doing before. You probably just kept using the same base path to get the parent.

Here is an good sample : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Get-upper-folders-in-443e975a

Hopes this help you.

Comment: I stored the path in a string using this `Dim lv as String` and `lvs = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text.ToString` and I did this one to remove the last folder path `Dim s As String = Form2.TextBox1.Text` and `s.Replace("\" & lvs, " ").TrimEnd()` but it still goes back to the parent folder.

Comment: Can you edit your post with your fully code please ?

Comment: @user2041732, did you look at the code sample Francois Borgies recommended? All operations are done on a string where the samples show returning a upper folder or all folders parent to the folder given at the start. A good visual is the screenshot here the top most index is the original folder provided and the lowest index is the root of the drive.

Comment: @KarenPayne
Please look at my updated code. Thanks~!!

Comment: @user2041732, not sure what to say as I have not worked with a ListView for over 10 years. Besides that I see nothing in the updated code using my suggestion, sorry I can't assist.

Comment: @FrancoisBorgies Hi, do you have a time?=) can you see my updated post? Thanks!

Comment: @KarenPayne uhm it's about removing an element in an `Array` that cannot be repeated. not the `ListView`. =)

Comment: I see no array, only a list(Of String). You can use the Contains method of the list to see if an item exists or not as Contains in your case accepts a string and returns a Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way do this:

```
Dim path As String = @"C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4"
Dim newPath As String = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(path, @"..\"));
```

If you want to go 2level up then try `@"..\..\"`

Comment: why does it go to the parent folder? not 1 upper folder from the third subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Child As String = "C:\Parent\Child"
Dim Parent As String = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Child).FullName
```